# c# mysql datetime to unix time

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the following problem.  The timeformat my database gives me back depends on the server settings.
So, if I do this query:

```
string query = "SELECT d.id, i.name, d.address, d.sensor, d.value, d.made, d.received, s.type, r.name AS room
            FROM info AS i
            RIGHT JOIN data AS d ON i.address = d.address AND i.sensor = d.sensor
            LEFT  JOIN sensor_types AS s ON i.type = s.id
            LEFT  JOIN room AS r ON i.room = r.id
            WHERE i.address = '" + address + "'
            && i.sensor  = '" + sensor  + "'
            && DATE(d.received) BETWEEN '" + start + "' AND '" + end + "'";
```

On server 1 I get back for today `2013-12-23 2:29:14` and on server 2 I get back `23-12-2013 2:29:14`.

In some cases I need the unixtime so I use this function for it, which works fine in case 1 but gives an error in case 2:

```
public string DateTimeToUnixTime(string text)
{
    DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    TimeSpan span = (myDate - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime());

    //return the total seconds (which is a UNIX timestamp)
    return ((double)span.TotalSeconds).ToString();

}
```

What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to convert datetime to unix time. 
You can use **UNIX_TIMESTAMP()** function of MySQL for that.

Try this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Dec 23 2013 02:29AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p'))
```

You can read more [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-unix_timestamp-function.php).

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Not saying it's the *best* way, but if the only possible formats are those two, you could test for one using `DateTime.TryParseExact`, and if it fails, assume it's the other format.

```
DateTime myDate;

if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate);
{
    myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```